# raise event handler attached to element

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to raise event handler attached  to element (`#scheduleLink`).
I have a page (page1) with the following JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    loadPublicationTab(); // load partial veiw via ajax
    var tab = "@Model.ActiveTab";

    if (tab === "#scheduleLink") {
        $("#scheduleLink").trigger('click');
        alert("true");
    } 
    else {
        alert("false");
        loadPublicationList(-1, 1); 
    }        
});

function loadPublicationTab() {
    $(".wrap_tabs").load("/Publication/GetPublicationTab?mainPage=" + false + "&isEvent=" + true);
}
```

The `loadPublicationTab` return the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#scheduleLink").click(function () {
            loadScheduleEvent();
            $(".wrap_tabs").find("a").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
        });
    });
</script>
// other html
```

The `#scheduleLink` located in other page and triger not work.  How to do this properly?
Thanks.

Comment: `$("#scheduleLink").length == 0` am I right?

Comment: Can you post the markup of scheduleLink? How are these two pages linked?

Comment: is `loadScheduleEvent();` async method?

Comment: @user348173, so is it clear now? the element just doesn't exist!

Comment: @Yorgo: there is .load() function. load() is not async, may be.

Comment: @gdoron: yes, but I can understand where to locate my code that is works

Comment: @gdoron: oh, I solved it. I move code to callback of loadPublicationTab function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

loadPublicationTab function work async. So `#scheduleLink` is not load on document.ready. You initiliaze the event on .`load()` function success

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".wrap_tabs").load("/Publication/GetPublicationTab?mainPage=" + false + "&isEvent=" + true, 
    function(){
     var tab = "@Model.ActiveTab";

    if (tab === "#scheduleLink") {
        $("#scheduleLink").trigger('click');
        alert("true");
    } 
    else {
        alert("false");
        loadPublicationList(-1, 1); 
    }    
});

});
```